# React native ToolbarAndroid action icon not working

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native vector icons to display icons for the actions on the toolbar. But it doesn't seem to work.

Imports & Icon

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const myIcon = (<Icon name="compass" size={30} color="#900" />)
```

Main view

```
 <View style={styles.containerToolbar}>
     <ToolbarAndroid style={styles.toolbar}
         title="Test"
         actions={toolbarActions}
         onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}>
     </ToolbarAndroid>
 </View>

var toolbarActions = [
    {title: 'Compass', icon:{myIcon} show: 'always'}
];
```

Comment: Where is your onActionSelected method?

Comment: Why does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the actions icon like this -

```
var toolbarActions = [
  {title:'Compass', iconName:'compass', iconColor:"#900", iconSize:30, show:'always'}
];
```

Furthermore you need to use `Icon.ToolbarAndroid` instead of `ToolbarAndroid`.

```
<Icon.ToolbarAndroid
  actions={toolbarActions}
  ....
>
```

More details here - https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#usage-with-toolbarandroid

Comment: Don't think you read the question carefully. I am trying to set icon to the action not the navIcon